# Scripting ASP.NET MVC Views Stored In The Database [Haacked.com]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Following Philip Haack's article Scripting ASP.NET MVC Views Stored In The Database [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx), does anyone have a working example of building a view from a database?

Since Phil's server crashed, the download has been broken and he hasn't, as yet, fixed it. So, does anyone have that download or do they have a working example of doing the same thing?

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a copy and I've posted it here:

http://www.2shared.com/file/11998124/e0155ea5/IronRubyViews-In-Db.html

Comment: That file appears to no longer be valid...do you still have it?